# Template literal with function calls

Tags: javascript

I recently found out, through [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/),  about a new way of calling a function that takes a string as a paremeters. It basically goes like this :

```js
console.log('some strings'.split``)
```

For some reason, we don't need the parentheses for this code to be valid.

This imply that you could also create custom function that takes a string as a parameter

```js
function appendSomething(string) {
  return string + " something else";
}


console.log(appendSomething`some thing`);
```

I was wondering about the use cases of such feature. Aside from code golfing or maybe minifying code, I don't see any good use case and find this synthax rather confusing. Why would you use this ?